# For loop updating dictionary values but not affecting output

Tags: python

I am trying to iterate over sentences in a file, picking the 'best' sentence (which is the sentence with the largest amount of rare diphones(sounds)), and after a sentence has been picked, changing the dictionary value of each diphone in the sentence to 0, so that the diphone isn't picked again (because I want to ensure that every possible diphone has been picked).

I have written code for this but can't see why it is not affecting output, as when I check the value for one of the dictionary keys which has been picked at the beginning of the for loop, it has been set to 0. My code is:

```
diphone_frequencies = {...}
diphone_frequencies_original = copy.deepcopy(diphone_frequencies)

line_score = {}
best_utts = []

for i in range(650):
    # Open the file and put all its lines in a list. Once.
    with open('recipe_diphone_utts.txt') as file:

        # Read the file lines one by one.
        for line in file:
            line = line.rstrip('\r\n')
            if line in best_utts:
                continue # Skip previously picked sentences.
            score = 0.0
            # Add a score to the line depending on its content.
            for word in line.split():
                score += float(diphone_frequencies[word])
            line_score[line] = score/len(line.split())

        # Sort each lines based on their score and get the best.
        best_sentence = max(line_score.keys(), key=(lambda k: line_score[k]))
        best_utts.append(best_sentence)
        print(best_sentence)

        # Each unique word of this iteration's best sentence has its score set to 0.
        for item in set(best_sentence.split()):
            diphone_frequencies[item] = 0

        if all(value == 0 for value in diphone_frequencies.values()):
            diphone_frequencies = diphone_frequencies_original
```

EDIT: This is solved, however I cannot accept my own answer right now; the issue was having the for loop after opening the document; the code worked when I put

```
for i in range(600):
```

before

```
with open('recipe_diphone_utts.txt') as file:
```

EDIT 2:

The main problem faced is solved and I have changed the code as such, however the line:

```
if line in best_utts:
    continue
```

Is supposed to ensure that multiple instances of the same line are not picked again once the dictionary values are reset, however it is causing the same sentence to be picked as best sentence over and over again so I need some other way to prevent the same sentence being picked multiple times.

Comment: Yes, what is `diphone_frequencies`? That variable is not initialised

Comment: Sorry, forgot to include it as I had some old code between the dictionary and the code I was using, have added it here

Comment: You can remove `file.close()` as using a `with open` automatically closes the file at the end of its scope.

Comment: You're reading the entire file on the first iteration of the outer loop.  That doesn't seem to make much sense.

Comment: What would you suggest I do instead? I'm not entirely sure what you mean

Comment: I can see that that is what's happening, however I don't see why the dictionary values are not affecting it, and by extension how I should change it so that the dictionary values do affect it

Comment: Oh I get it. You want to pick the best sentence of the file, then *all the words in this sentence* have their score reduced to 0 for the next iteration scoring calculations?

Comment: Yes, in practice it's actually sounds for a speech synthesiser, the logic being that I need at least one version of each sound to avoid having missing sounds, and then once all sounds have been collected, finding the best sentences as normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently `best_utts == [best_sentence] * 600` because of the outer loop, and `best_sentence` is the sentence with the best score, compared to all the other sentences (lines) of the file.

To get the 600 best sentences I would go like this:

```
diphone_frequencies = {...}
diphone_frequencies_original = copy.deepcopy(diphone_frequencies)

line_score = {}
best_utts = []

# Open the file and put all its lines in a list. Once. 
with open('recipe_diphone_utts.txt') as file:
    all_lines = file.readlines()

for i in range(600):
    print(diphone_frequencies['f_@@r'])

    # Read the file lines one by one.
    for line in all_lines:
        line = line.rstrip()
        if line in best_utts:
            line_score[line] = 0
            continue # Skip previously picked sentences.
        score = 0.0
        # Add a score to the line depending on its content.
        for word in line.split():
            score += float(diphone_frequencies[word])
        line_score[line] = score/len(line.split())

    # Sort each lines based on their score and get the best.
    best_sentence = max(line_score.keys(), key=(lambda k: line_score[k]))
    best_utts.append(best_sentence)

    # Each unique word of this iteration's best sentence has its score set to 0.
    for item in set(best_sentence.split()):
        diphone_frequencies[item] = 0

    if all(value == 0 for value in diphone_frequencies.values()):
        diphone_frequencies = diphone_frequencies_original

print(best_utts)
```

Also `file.close()` is not needed at the end since you are using `with open ... as file` instead of `file = open(...)`.

Comment: Thanks for the response! However the fact that the bottom code doesn't affect the for loop is what I am most struggling with, as it includes the weighting code to find the sentences, and has to run after each sentence has been picked, do you have any idea how I could change the code to allow for this?

Comment: Yes, I'll edit the answer to make it work. Is my understanding correct in the other comment?

Comment: Yes, changing the dictionary values for the chosen words from each sentence to 0

Comment: Ok I have changed things and poped a for loop at the end since you can use `set()` on a list directly. Why do you need to reset the frequencies after all the words are spent? We could just stop the loop there instead.

Comment: I could, but if it only takes say 200 sentences to get all the diphones in the dictionary, it will be a very small database, and in general the larger the database the better. I have chosen 600 sentences as it around the same size as a database that I will be able to measure against.

Comment: True, but I don't understand how this would not lead to the 200 best sentences being added three times to the list. Should we ignore lines that are already best sentences then? In the `for line in file` loop.

Comment: That's a good point, yeah it will need to ignore sentences which have already been picked, as having the same 200 sentences three times would not be useful, also I just ran that code using set() on the list and it didn't affect the output

Comment: @Guimoute: It still looks like the code is intending to read the file 600 times, which won't happen. Surely the file should be read once, immediately after the `with open` and then scan `line_score` 600 times?

Comment: Surely. See my modification.

Comment: Ah, that's much better!

Comment: I like how you skipped previously skipped sentences, my idea was going to be very unpythonic and probably inefficient, I'm running the code now and it looks like it'll take about half an hour but it looks like it's fixed, thanks a lot for all your help @Guimoute

Comment: The code just finished running and the output is the first sentence 600 times as before, I will try running it again with for i in range(600) coming before opening the file as it looks as if that is the problem.

Comment: I found that the line 'if line in best_utts: continue' for some reason was causing the same sentence to be chosen over and over again

Comment: You could test with 5 loops instead of 600. If it doesn't work for a few iterations it won't work for many. I am confused about the skipping part causing issues :\ Maybe the cause is somewhere else too.

Comment: Yeah I just presumed it would work when I ran yours so didn't think to put in a way of checking, I've added a 'print(best_sentence)' within the for loop so I can stop it if the same line is picked more than once, and I have tried running it with the if...continue left in and commented out so it seems as though it is the reason

Comment: Curiously, I added a print('line is in best_utts') into the if...continue statement, and it printed the best utterance, then the print statement, then the best utterance again, so it is being triggered but is not working

Comment: @Guimoute The issue was that the continue statement didn't consider that the line_score of the best sentence would not change, so I have edited your answer to change the line_score to 0 if the line is in best_utts

Comment: Turns out that didn't work either so I made a set consisting of the intersection() files in the database and the chosen sentences

Answer (score 1):

I found that the main mistake that I made was putting

```
for i in range(600):
```

after the

```
with open('recipe_diphone_utts.txt') as file
```

when I changed it to having the with open... be inside the for loop, it worked.

Comment: See the updated answer from @Guimoute. He reads the entire file in once and then loops over the contents 600 times.